# Add list of columns above a certain threshold

Tags: r

Say I have a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(rbind(c(10,1,5,4), c(6,0,3,10), c(7,1,10,10))) 
colnames(df) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")


df
a  b  c  d
10 1  5  4
6  0  3 10
7  1 10 10
```

And a vector of numbers (which correspond to the four column names a,b,c,d)

```
threshold <- c(7,1,5,8)
```

I need to compare each row in the data frame to the vector.  When the value in the data frame meets or exceeds that in the vector, I need to return the column name.  The output would be:

```
a   b   c   d   cols
10  1   5   4    a,b,c    #10>7, 1>=1, 5>=5
6   0   3   10   d        #10>8
7   1   10  10   a,b,c,d  ##7>=7, 1>=1, 10>=5, 10>-8
```

The column cols can be a string that simply lists the columns where the value is exceeded.

Is there any clever way to do this?  I'm migrating an old Excel function and I can write a loop or something, but I thought there almost had to be a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need `which` and the desired output is for comma separated values:

```
df$cols <- apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) toString(names(df)[-1][x >= threshold]))
df
  id  a b  c  d       cols
1 aa 10 1  5  4    a, b, c
2 bb  6 0  3 10          d
3 cc  7 1 10 10 a, b, c, d
```

Answer (score 3):

We can also try

```
i1 <- which(df >=threshold[col(df)], arr.ind=TRUE)
df$cols <- unname(tapply(names(df)[i1[,2]], i1[,1], toString))
df$cols
#[1] "a, b, c"    "d"          "a, b, c, d"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
df$cols <- apply(df[, 2:5], 1, function(x) names(df[, 2:5])[which(x >= threshold)])
```